# Scraping javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape running routes, to geoprocess in R, from the following site: http://runkeeper.com/user/127244964/route/1149604

I am trying to do to that with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
import csv
import os
import requests

page1 = urllib2.urlopen("http://runkeeper.com/user/212579518/route/513771")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1)
print(soup)
```

When I print the results I see that the data that I need is on a text/javascript:

var routePoints = [{"latitude":38.918704,"longitude":-77.036478,"deltaDistance":0,"type":"StartPoint","altitude":40,"deltaPause":0}

I need to scrape the variables inside the dictionary. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search the soup data with regex and load it into an object for your usage.

```
import re
import json

point_re = re.compile('.*routePoints =(.*);')
point_json = point_re.search(str(soup)).group(1)
point_data = json.loads(point_json)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get all the points that I need. If I wanted to save this to a csv file what would be your suggestion? Also if you have any suggestions on a good tutorial for BeautifulSoup tutorial/book I would appreciate it.

Comment: you could use http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html but it is  just as easy to open a file and write the lines you want as long as you are just dumping numerics it will be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to strip everything outside the square brackets (or alternately, to only select the content of the outermost brackets), then use `json.loads` on the brackets.